# How to change URL format in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have a url link  like

http://www.mysite.com/category/post/?week=week-4&cat=getstarted

How to change my above link to

http://www.mysite.com/category/post/week-4/getstarted

When i try to change the url to more than three segments it showing error page not found. How to ignore the additional segments in url by wordpress.

Comment: You need to rewrite URL, learn more about URL rewriting with .htaccess files, and obviously if you use the urls directly like `page.php/2/article-name` without rewriting the url it will think you are providing a path to literal directory

Answer (score 0):

Go into your Wordpress admin.

Go to Settings >>> Permalinks

Use one of the structures Wordpress provides or just enter your own custom structure, such as:

yourdomain.com/%category%/%postname%/

Comment: I check the above Permalinks. But it works for two segments like categorey, postname . After that it shows page not found.

Comment: Can you put your URL in here so I can see?

Comment: do you have a proper link?

Comment: It would help to see a regular link, like CellarRoom said, but I'd use this plugin; it works for me and is simple to use.  It hasn't been updated in 2 years, but it's fine for WP 3.5.1 and it doesn't matter what theme/framework you're using:  http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-301-redirects/