# Change wordpress URL format through plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Is it possible to [change the WordPress URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14874944/875020) format by a self-developed module/plugin, e.g. during installation?

Would this also work for [non-selfhosted pages on WP.com](https://en.support.wordpress.com/coming-from-self-hosted/#a-note-on-permalinks) and various themes, so its generally applyable?

I know WP tries to change the `.htaccess`, so one way would be a manual manipulation, but id prefer an official/well supported mechanism.